# Why I cannot return my object?

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload "+" for the class bigInt(use linkedlist to save a long int).I return the sum of x1,x2 in the function as shown below.

```
friend bigInt operator+(bigInt &x1,bigInt &x2){
         bigInt sum;
         int lenx1=x1.length();
         int lenx2=x2.length();
         int len_sum;
         len_sum=lenx1>lenx2?lenx1:lenx2;
         if(len_sum==lenx1){
            for(int i=len_sum-1;i>=lenx2;--i){
                sum.insert(0,x1.visit(i)->data);
            }
            for(int i=lenx2-1;i>=0;--i){
                int add=x1.visit(i)->data+x2.visit(i)->data;
                if(add>9){
                    sum.visit(i+1)->data+=1;
                    add-=10;
                }
                sum.insert(0,add);
            }
         }
         else{
             for(int i=len_sum-1;i>=lenx1;--i){
                sum.insert(0,x2.visit(i)->data);
            }
            for(int i=lenx1-1;i>=0;--i){
                int add=x1.visit(i)->data+x2.visit(i)->data;
                if(add>9){
                    sum.visit(i+1)->data+=1;
                    add-=10;
                }
                sum.insert(0,add);
            }
         }
         cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;//output is right here.
         return sum;
     }
```

But in main function，sum appears to be nothing,i.e.it just cout a+b= (where shout have output sum output nothing at all)
main function:

```
void main(){
  bigInt a,b,sum;
  cout<<"please input a big int a:"<<endl;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<"please input a big int b:"<<endl;
  cin>>b;
  sum=b+a;
  cout<<a<<"+"<<b<<"="<<sum<<endl;
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

I have overload "<<" and ">>" already.But I don't understand what's wrong here.I 'll appreciate any help.

---

Thanks for the suggestions.I overload "="now. And "sum=b" works.But the error above seem to remain:(

```
     bigInt &operator=(bigInt &right)
 {
     if(this==&right) return *this;
     clear();
     bigInt resl;
     int len=right.length();
     for(int i=0;i<len;++i)
     {
         insert(i,right.visit(i)->data);
     }
     return *this;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get the sum in main function". Compiler error, runtime error? What happens?

Comment: Sorry for my  poor expression and I have modify my question. Actually, the error is that sum can't "cout" in main function.

Comment: What is es1`supposed to be in your assignment operator? You may want to use a debugger to see what's contained in your objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to guess what could be wrong. Would be easier if you gave access to  `bigInt` class code.

`sum=b+a;` will use the assignment operator (`operator=`). Apparently (from what you posted and said), you did not overload it. So compiler will use default implementation copying objects attribute (which may be unsafe if your `bigInt` class uses pointers and may end up with `bigInt` result being empty...but it's hard to be sure because you did not post `bigInt` class code).

You should either overload `operator=` (good and best solution, [see this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)), or avoid using it as proposed below (you may need a [copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/), except if compiler is smart enough not to use it by performing a [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)):

```
int main(){
  bigInt a,b;
  cout<<"please input a big int a:"<<endl;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<"please input a big int b:"<<endl;
  cin>>b;
  bigInt sum(b+a); // assignment operator is not used anymore
  cout<<a<<"+"<<b<<"="<<sum<<endl;
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

Note that it's a good practice to define your own copy constructor and assignment operator to avoid this sort of problem. [See this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It's OK not to declare them if all class attributes are copiable, it's not OK if they are not (like raw pointers).

Comment: Downoting without commenting should be forbidden....

Comment: "Note that it's a good practice to ALWAYS define your own copy constructor and assignment operator", I'd say you should almost never have to do this. Also, there's not enough information in the post to answer. And `void main()`.

Comment: I do not agree that you should ALWAYS define your own copy constructor and assignment operator. IMO the opposite is true.

Comment: I didn't mean 'never define your own copy constructor and assignment op'. I should have said you rarely want to.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Updated the post, it's true if all attributes are copiable you don't need to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to overload the copy constructor and assignment operator as well.

When you perform `sum=a+b` the assignment operator should copy the contents of the temporary sum object (right side) into sum (left side)

Without overloading assignment, the compiler will perform a "shallow copy", which duplicates each member of your class. Any pointers you have in the class will be copied, but the underlying data will not be moved.

This means your main sum variable will point to your function copy's data. However, that sum object is temporary and deleted after the assignment, leaving your main sum incomplete.

Your overloaded assignment operator needs to do a "deep copy", which recreates a bigInt by reading the values from the linked list in the right side into the bigInt on the left side

Comment: How do you know that is the problem? Do you have access to OP's code?

Comment: The OP indicates that the sum object in the addition operator is correct and prints before returning it, but that the assigned version doesn't work. I can easily infer that the assignment operator isn't correctly overloaded